# Update nested Json in Mysql/Mariadb

Tags: json, nested, sql-update, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

```json
{
  "people": {
    "Man": {
      "Employee": "50",
      "Student": "91",
      "Artist": "80",
      "Clark": "50"
    },
    "Woman": {
      "Employee": "21",
      "Student": "01",
      "Artist": "00",
      "k3": "30",
      "Clark": "68"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I Update `Employee` Value From `Man` Object. I want something similar to below mysql query.

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET Column = JSON_SET(Column, '$.people.Man.Employee', '51') 
  WHERE Id=1234567890;

MariaDB [**********]> SELECT VERSION();

+--------------------------------------------+
| VERSION()                                  |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 10.3.17-MariaDB-1:10.3.17+maria~bionic-log |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, fix the `keys` within the JSON column by adding quotes for each, and `values` by adding quotes for some which starts with zeroes and go on with other digits.

Then apply :

```
UPDATE tab
   SET Col = JSON_SET(
       Col,
       "$.people.Man.Employee", "50",
       "$.people.Man.Employee", "51"
       )
 WHERE ID = 1234567890;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a6b8cb42f2066ce172bb281ec2063c0d)</kbd>

Comment: Thank You Very Much. This is perfectly Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Even, I don't see any problem with the following

```
UPDATE tab
SET 
    Col = JSON_SET(Col, '$.people.Man.Employee', '51')
WHERE
    Id = 1234567890;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f55912956dec31e96048540ef7fc9aba)